# Orion CB doesn't handle IoT agent replies

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm developing a system in which I use Orion CB as main event bus making use also of the iotagent node lib in order to have an interface with third party APIs.

Now what happens is that I register a new device on the iotagent with only lazy attributes, one of which should be a json string.

Overriding the query handler and its subfunctions I tried both to stringify this json string and leaving it in json format and this is what i get:

1) Stringify the json:
When I query Orion to retrieve the entity it replies that that entity does not exist with status code 404. Looking on the iotagent debug log I see that its response is exactly what I was expecting (with all attributes well formatted) and it ends with "statusCode":{"code": 200, "reasonPhrase": "OK"} so it seems that the iotagent is replying to Orion with status code 200 (success!).

2) Leave the json as it is:
When I query Orion to retrieve the entity it replies with status code 200, all attributes are ok but the one with the json, that is empty. Again, looking at the iotagent debug log I see that the response is what I'd like to see querying to Orion and it ends with "statusCode":{"code": 200, "reasonPhrase": "OK"}.

What is happening here? What could be the problem in the first case? It seems that for some reason Orion doesn't like the iotagent response and it says that the entity doesn't exist. While in the second case i think the problem could be in the data structure that is not allowed (json as attribute value).

Am I missing something? I'd be glad if someone can help me with this trouble, let me know if you require more information.

Edit:

This is how I'm provisioning the device:

```
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "taxi_list",
            "entity_name": "taxi_list",
            "entity_type": "taxilist",
            "lazy": [
                {
                    "name": "taxiPosition",
                    "type": "StructuredValue"
                },
                {
                    "name": "error",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "corsaRuntime",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The attribute in which I need to have the json is "taxiPosition", so its type is "StructuredValue". Creating the response I just use JSON.parse() on the payload retrieved by the 'device' and assign this value to the attribute like:

```
responses.push({
                name: 'taxiPositions',
                type: 'StructuredValue',
                value: [{...}, {...}]
        });
```

Where the value is an array of objects with simple one-level key-value pairs formatted like this:

```
{ "idTaxi": "100", "idStato": "1", "lat": "90.843227100000000", "lng": "64.228254600000000", "nome": "Name", "cognome": "Surname", "licenza": "24XX", "cellulare": "+39320662332XX", "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu", "targa": "XX000XX", "modelloAuto": "Focus SW", "marcaAuto": "Ford", "annoImmatricolazione": "2020", "passeggeri": "4", "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05", "rank": "4.2", "n_corse": "6", "os": "A", "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51", "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50", "radio": "1", "pos": "0", "nome_radio": null, "iban": "" }
```

When I attempt to do it passing the value as a string the code is the same but the type for the attribute is "string" and the value is obtained by using JSON.stringify() on the previously parsed json.

To query the entity from Orion I simply make a call to /v2/entities/taxi_list

Comment: Please specify the code you are using in both cases. My guess is that your problem is with the json structure you are passing to Orion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added more informations. I think the problem is on the structure too.  If I have understood correctly how Orion and the iotagent work togeter they use the NGSIv1 format (and Orion translate NGSIv2 requests into NGSIv1 in order to do that). Is it possible that the json value is not supported in that version?
But anyway it doesn't explain why passing a string instead of json Orion replies with a 404 status code.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/structured_attribute_valued/

Comment: Or try using a list like the following: `"value": ["first", "second", "third"]`. I mean, without the names of the "values". And locate the specific values just by the position.

Comment: According to what is reported on the link you posted the json structure I'm using should be completely compatible with both NSGIv1 and NGSIv2.
Anyway I tryed to simplify the structure with the one you suggested and I get always the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some formats, and the two last are the best option:
Here is an validate json:

> POST /v2/entities

```
{
            "device_id": "taxi_list",
            "entity_name": "taxi_list",
            "entity_type": "taxilist",
            "lazy": [
                {
                    "name": "taxiPosition",
                    "type": "StructuredValue"
                },
                {
                    "name": "error",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "corsaRuntime",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
}
```

> Answer:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "entity id length: 0, min length supported: 1"
}
```

> POST /v2/entities

```
{
            "id": "taxi_list",
            "name": "taxi_list",
            "type": "taxilist",
            "lazy": [
                {
                    "name": "taxiPosition",
                    "type": "StructuredValue"
                },
                {
                    "name": "error",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "corsaRuntime",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
}
```

> Answer:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"
}
```

> POST /v2/entities

```
{
            "id": "taxi_list",
            "name": "taxi_list",
            "type": "taxilist",
            "taxiPosition":{
              "type": "StructuredValue",
                            "value":
                            { "idTaxi": "100", "idStato": "1", "lat": "90.843227100000000", "lng": "64.228254600000000", "nome": "Name", "cognome": "Surname", "licenza": "24XX", "cellulare": "+39320662332XX", "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu", "targa": "XX000XX", "modelloAuto": "Focus SW", "marcaAuto": "Ford", "annoImmatricolazione": "2020", "passeggeri": "4", "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05", "rank": "4.2", "n_corse": "6", "os": "A", "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51", "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50", "radio": "1", "pos": "0", "nome_radio": null, "iban": "" }

                }
}
```

> Answer:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"
}
```

> Best example
>
> POST v2/entities?options=keyValues

```
{
                "id": "taxi_list",
                "name": "taxi_list",
                "type": "taxilist",
                "taxiPosition":
                                { "idTaxi": "100", "idStato": "1", "lat": "90.843227100000000", "lng": "64.228254600000000", "nome": "Name", "cognome": "Surname", "licenza": "24XX", "cellulare": "+39320662332XX", "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu", "targa": "XX000XX", "modelloAuto": "Focus SW", "marcaAuto": "Ford", "annoImmatricolazione": "2020", "passeggeri": "4", "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05", "rank": "4.2", "n_corse": "6", "os": "A", "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51", "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50", "radio": "1", "pos": "0", "nome_radio": null, "iban": "" }


    }
```

> Answer:

```
NONE
```

> HTTP Answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

> GET /v2/entities

```
[
    {
        "id": "taxi_list",
        "type": "taxilist",
        "name": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "taxi_list",
            "metadata": {}
        },
        "taxiPosition": {
            "type": "StructuredValue",
            "value": {
                "idTaxi": "100",
                "idStato": "1",
                "lat": "90.843227100000000",
                "lng": "64.228254600000000",
                "nome": "Name",
                "cognome": "Surname",
                "licenza": "24XX",
                "cellulare": "+39320662332XX",
                "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu",
                "targa": "XX000XX",
                "modelloAuto": "Focus SW",
                "marcaAuto": "Ford",
                "annoImmatricolazione": "2020",
                "passeggeri": "4",
                "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05",
                "rank": "4.2",
                "n_corse": "6",
                "os": "A",
                "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51",
                "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50",
                "radio": "1",
                "pos": "0",
                "nome_radio": null,
                "iban": ""
            },
            "metadata": {}
        }
    }
]
```

Other format:

> POST /v2/entities?options=keyValues

```
{
            "id": "taxi_list3",
            "name": "taxi_list",
            "type": "taxilist",
            "lazy": 
                        [
                            {
                                "name":"taxiPosition",
                                 "type": "StructuredValue",
                                "value":
                                                { "idTaxi": "100", "idStato": "1", "lat": "90.843227100000000", "lng": "64.228254600000000", "nome": "Name", "cognome": "Surname", "licenza": "24XX", "cellulare": "+39320662332XX", "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu", "targa": "XX000XX", "modelloAuto": "Focus SW", "marcaAuto": "Ford", "annoImmatricolazione": "2020", "passeggeri": "4", "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05", "rank": "4.2", "n_corse": "6", "os": "A", "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51", "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50", "radio": "1", "pos": "0", "nome_radio": null, "iban": "" }
                         },
                         {
                    "name": "error",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "corsaRuntime",
                    "type": "string"
                }

                         ]             
}
```

> GET /v2/entities/taxi_list3

```
{
    "id": "taxi_list3",
    "type": "taxilist",
    "lazy": {
        "type": "StructuredValue",
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "taxiPosition",
                "type": "StructuredValue",
                "value": {
                    "idTaxi": "100",
                    "idStato": "1",
                    "lat": "90.843227100000000",
                    "lng": "64.228254600000000",
                    "nome": "Name",
                    "cognome": "Surname",
                    "licenza": "24XX",
                    "cellulare": "+39320662332XX",
                    "email": "xxxxxx@xxxx.eu",
                    "targa": "XX000XX",
                    "modelloAuto": "Focus SW",
                    "marcaAuto": "Ford",
                    "annoImmatricolazione": "2020",
                    "passeggeri": "4",
                    "dataCreazione": "2014-05-05",
                    "rank": "4.2",
                    "n_corse": "6",
                    "os": "A",
                    "dataOraInizioTurno": "05-01-2018 07:51",
                    "dataOraFineTurno": "05-01-2018 11:50",
                    "radio": "1",
                    "pos": "0",
                    "nome_radio": null,
                    "iban": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "error",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "status",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "corsaRuntime",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "taxi_list",
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

Then, you can use:

> ?options=keyValues

The entity in this example "id": "taxi_list", is the more interesting. Because the Orion create the structured format, and Orion will validate. In the payload of tax_list3, the string in values will represent values, whithout an Orion validation.

Answer (score 0):

Aragona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8362361/f-aragona)

What is your Fiware Orion version you use? For the IotAgent are you using the latest one?

By other hand it's highly recommend to use docker-compose to deploy all the servicies you are using unless Mosquitto

```
version : "2"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: --nojournal
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - "27017"
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo
    expose:
      - "1026"
```

For Mosquitto and for the IotAgent, you must install it from sources.

```
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json.git
```

Once cloned and installed it, you must set up `config.js` according your IP containers. Attached I give you some scripts in order to create an entity and a device. It's important to follow step by step in order to assign the `device` to the `entity`

**Scripts**

**1.Create Service**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    curl -X POST -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
"services": [
    {
          "resource": "/",
          "apikey": "1234",
          "type": "multiSensor",
          "cbroker":"172.18.0.3:1026"
    }
    ]
}' 'http://localhost:4041/iot/services'
```

Note:

- The `"apikey": "1234"` field must be define in `config.js` IotAgent JSON file.
- The `"cbroker":"172.18.0.3"` field is the ORION IP container

**2 Create Device**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    curl -X POST -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ 
    "devices": [ 
        { 
            "device_id": "sensor00", 
            "entity_name": "R2-D2", 
            "entity_type": "robot",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "name": "temperature",
                "type": "celsius"
              },
              {
                "name": "Position",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

' 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices'
```

**3.Send meassures to OCB** (Using IotAgent-JSON cause payload)

```
mosquitto_pub -t /1234/sensor00/attrs -m '{"temperature": 40.2,"Position": "left"}'
```

**4.Query to Orion to see results**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -d '{
    "entities": [
        {
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "R2-D2",
            "type": "robot"
        }
    ]
}' 'http://172.18.0.3:1026/NGSI10/queryContext'
```

Please let me know if you solve it.

fernando.mendez@atos.net

Comment: Hi [F.Aragona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8362361/f-aragona)

Did you triy? Something news?

Please let me know. 

Thanks, Fernando